# Can't upsize the container memory and cpu in azure

Tags: azure, containers

I am struggling with a azure container sizing problem. I am using linux-container in western europe. I built my containers from a code-server with a `yaml` file. The basic setup is that I use:

```
CPU: 1
Memory: 4
```

and when I try to change it to :

```
CPU: 1
Memory: 8
```

or:

```
CPU: 2
Memory: 8
```

The command i use is:
`az container create -g {config["general"]["resource_group"]} -f container_deployment.yaml'`

And the `yaml.file`:

```
additional_properties: {}
apiVersion: '2023-05-01'
extended_location: null
location: westeurope
name: XXX
properties:
  containers:
  - name: "c0"
    properties:
      environmentVariables:
      - name: INDEX
        value: 0      
      image: ABC.azurecr.io/model-factory:v28
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGB: 4
  - name: "c1"
    properties:
      environmentVariables:
      - name: INDEX
        value: 1      
      image: ABC.azurecr.io/model-factory:v28
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGB: 4
  - name: "c2"
    properties:
      environmentVariables:
      - name: INDEX
        value: 2      
      image: ABC.azurecr.io/model-factory:v28
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGB: 4
  - name: "c3"
    properties:
      environmentVariables:
      - name: INDEX
        value: 3
      image: ABC.azurecr.io/model-factory:v28
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGB: 4
  imageRegistryCredentials: # Credentials to pull a private image
  - server: ABC.azurecr.io
    username: "username"
    password: "pw"
  initContainers: []
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  sku: Standard
  subnetIds:
  - id: /subscriptions/abcd
tags: {}
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

I always built 4 containers in my container app.

I get the error:

> Deploying Containers
> ERROR: (InvalidContainerGroupUpdate) The updates on container group 'XXX' are invalid. If you are going to update the Memory Resource (old "16", new "32") for a container group, you must delete it first and then create a new one.
> Code: InvalidContainerGroupUpdate
> Message: The updates on container group 'XXX' are invalid. If you are going to update the Memory Resource (old "16", new "32") for a container group, you must delete it first and then create a new one.
> Traceback (most recent call last):

I wonder why this happens, because the offical [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability) say that I can upsize it to 4 and 16.

Comment: Regarding the memory allocation limits for Azure Container Instances, the limits vary by region and deployment type. You can refer to the [Azure Container Instances Region Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability) documentation for more information on the maximum CPU and memory sizes for your region and deployment type.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust memory or CPU resources for an Azure Container Instance, you must recreate the container group with the updated settings, as ACI doesn't support dynamic resource scaling for running instances. You need to first-

**Delete the Existing Container Group**: Remove the current container group using the Azure CLI:

```
az container delete -g [ResourceGroupName] -n [ContainerGroupName]
```

[image]

**Update the YAML Configuration**: Edit your `container_deployment.yaml` file to reflect the new resource requirements. For instance, to update to 2 CPUs and 8 GB of memory, modify the resources block:

```yaml
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 2
    memoryInGB: 8
```

**Recreate the Container Group**: Deploy the updated container group with the Azure CLI:

```
az container create -g [ResourceGroupName] -f container_deployment.yaml
```

or from portal
[image]

This process will ensure your container group is configured with the desired resource allocations.
[image]

References:

- [Troubleshoot common issues in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#issues-during-container-group-deployment)
- [Resource availability for Azure Container Instances in Azure regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you cannot create 4 containers with more then 1 cpu and 4 memory, because that would exceed the size limit. They add up to each other.